# Game including drawing balls and rolling dice.

Tags: probability

An urn contains $3$ black balls and $2$ red balls. we also consider a perfect die. a player draws $2$ balls successively and without replacement. if he draws $2$ black balls he wins and stop, otherwise he continues and he rolls the dice twice, if the sum obtained is even he wins.

Let $A=$"the player draws $2$ black balls"

Let $S=$"the player obtains an even sum of the dice."

Let $G=$"the player wins".

Determine the conditional probability $P(S|{\bar G})$ (where ${\bar G}$ is the complement event of $G$) and determine  $p(G)$.

My understanding is that $P(S|\bar G)=0$ because knowing that he did not win means that he cannot have an even sum.

On the other hand $p(G)=p(A)+p(S|\bar A)$ and $p(A)=\dfrac{p(3,2)}{p(5,2)}=\dfrac{6}{20}=\dfrac{3}{10}$ and $p(S)=p(S|A)+p(S|\bar A)=0+p(S|\bar A)$

So $p(G)=p(A)+p(S)$ where $P(S)=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Is my try correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $p(S|\bar{G})=0$

and $$p(G)=p(A)+p(\bar{A}\cap S)$$
$$=\frac{3}{10}+\frac{7}{10}\times\frac12=\frac{13}{20}$$

Comment: In your formula $p(G)=p(A)+p(\bar A \cap S)$, Is it a conditional probability $p(S|\bar A)$ or the probability of the intersection $p(S \cap \bar A)$. I thought it is a conditional probability because we don't roll the dice untill we are sure that he did not win by drawing two black balls.

Comment: it's $p(\bar{A}\cap S)=p(\bar{A})\times p(S|\bar{A})$ but $p(S|\bar{A})=p(S)$ by definition of event $S$